# [REDIS]: How to Delete All Keys on Master and Slave(s)?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-cli

I'm trying to delete all keys on both redis master and slave, but when I'm executing `flushall` or `flushdb` from `redis-cli` on master it deletes keys only on master, or vice versa if I'm deleting keys on slave it deletes keys only on slave.

What command should I use to delete all keys both on master and slave(s)?

Do I need to enable cluster support for this? Cause now it is desabled in my setup.

One more question, why there is no replication in case of using `flushall` or `flushdb` from `redis-cli`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You only need to call `FLUSHALL` or `FLUSHDB` on **every** master to remove all keys, when master syncs with slaves, slaves will remove all keys. However, you must ensure that the connection between master and slave is alive.

If you call these two commands on slaves (of course, the slave must be writable), keys on master won't be removed.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it works. I just haven't noticed that I executed flushall from slave both times because when you stop and start again master node, slave becomes master.

Comment: Please tell me whether removing on one master can remove on the other master and it's respective slave nodes?

Comment: @GopsAB NO, you CANNOT do that.